Why can't Gradle resolve project from github repo?
I have a library project on a github repo which has gradle as build tool, and I have another project that is an app depends on the library project, but the library project is not yet stable to be published, so I thought if I would add it as a dependency using sourceControl block.
my app settings.gradle.kts file looks like this:
sourceControl {
    gitRepository(uri("https://github.com/user/repo")) {
        producesModule("group:project")
    }
}

and build.gradle.kts file looks like this:
implementation("group:project") {
      version {
        branch = "main"
      }
    }

But when I execute ./gradlew build it doesn't work:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':distTar'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Git repository at https://github.com/user/repo did not contain a project publishing the specified dependency.             
Required by:
         root project :

Surprisingly, When I change the repo url to point at the local repo, i.e. change https://github.com/user/repo to file://path/to/repo It works, and the app get built successfully.
Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Try https://www.jitpack.io/ otherwise, you can publish snapshot or RC builds to indicate they're not full releases

@OneCricketeer I tried jitpack, but it requires group name to be explicitly in form com.github.[user]

In your dependencies, yes, but not in the actual code of the repo

@OneCricketeer It doesn't work either:
:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
Could not find com.github.user:repo:main-SNAPSHOT.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/user/repo/main-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/user/repo/main-SNAPSHOT/math-java-main-SNAPSHOT.pom
...


Well, it should not search repo.maven.apache.org, it should search jitpack.io https://docs.jitpack.io/

@OneCricketeer Yeah it actually searched it, but I coudn't print the full message because stackoverflow told me my comment is too long
